# HttpCalloutMock Test class Failing

Tags: unit-test, failing-tests, httpcalloutmock

I have a Class using MetadataService and different methods of it. I want to create a test class for the same but it is giving an error that my test class have HTTP callouts. I am using the HttpCalloutMock but still it is giving me the same error. The Class is using MetadataService, and it is calling multiple callouts which may be the problem

```
@isTest
private class CustomLabelHelperTest {

    static testMethod void createServiceTestMethod()
    {  
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        Test.startTest();
        MetadataService.MetadataPort service = CustomLabelHelper.createService();
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }

    static testMethod void readCustomLabelsTestMethod()
    {  
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        Test.startTest();
        Map<String, CustomLabelHelper.CustomLabelData> customLabelDataMap = CustomLabelHelper.readCustomLabels();
        Test.stopTest(); 
    }
}
```

Here my first method is getting passed but the second method is failing.

Comment: Can you post what the error message is? For all we know, it could be unrelated to the callout

Answer (score 1):

Are you using raw HTTP Callouts or SOAP calls via WSDL2Apex? The `MetadataService.MetadataPort` makes me suspect the latter.

In that case, your mock class needs to implement `WebServiceMock` rather than `HttpCalloutMock`. Then it will correctly mock the SOAP web service response.